# Converting Access Syntax into SQL Syntax

Tags: sql

I am trying to convert the below into from an Access Database Syntax to sql query syntax using Case-When-Then etc.  Can someone help me?

> SpreadType: IIf([mv_Loan_Ext1]![LoanPurposeTypeCode] In ("008","080"),"QRLF-" & IIf([FAReceivesPatronage]=0,"NPAT","PAT"),IIf([SecDistrictIndustryCode]="999","Non-QRLF",IIf([PriDistrictIndustryCode]="999","RHL",IIf([mv_Loan_Ext1]![LoanPurposeTypeCode]+0 Between 1 And 7,"Other home",IIf([FANoteIsParticipationPurchased]=1,IIf([mv_FANote]![BranchNbr]="092","100% GP","PP"),IIf([PatronagePoolCode]="14","FCE",IIf([YBSAgStart]<>"No" Or IIf(Trim([AgGrow_NoOperator]) Is Null,0,IIf(Trim([AgGrow_NoOperator])="" Or Trim([AgGrow_NoOperator])="No",0,1))+IIf(Trim([AgNiche]) Is Null,0,IIf(Trim([AgNiche])="" Or Trim([AgNiche])="No",0,1))+IIf(Trim([AgGrowOperator]) Is Null,0,IIf(Trim([AgGrowOperator])="" Or Trim([AgGrowOperator])="No",0,1))>0,"YBS AgStart",IIf([GrainInventoryLoan]="Yes","Grain Inventory",IIf([COVID19] Like "SBA*","PPP",IIf(IIf([FarmTypeAbbr]="",IIf([FCALoanTypeAbbr]="PRIT","FL",IIf([FCALoanTypeAbbr]="REMG","FL","")),[FarmTypeAbbr])<>"FL","General non-farmer","Core farmer loans"))))))))))

Comment: Is `mv_Loan_Ext1` a form?  Is yes, you can't.  You have to reference a table/column in sql.  You can't reference a form.

Comment: mv_Loan_Ext1 is a database in access

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite your query like this.  You just have too many embed ().  This is little mess.

```
select 
case when [mv_Loan_Ext1].[LoanPurposeTypeCode] in ('008', '080') then 'QRLF-' + case FAReceivesPatronage when 0 then 'NPAT' else 'PAT' end
     when [SecDistrictIndustryCode] = '999' THEN 'Non-QRLF'
     when ...
end
```

Comment: Agree it is a mess.  I didn't write it and am being asked to rewrite.  ugh thank you for your help

Comment: Can you help me with this peice of it?  IIf([mv_Loan_Ext1]![LoanPurposeTypeCode]+0 Between 1 And 7,"Other home"

Comment: What is the type of LoanPurposeTypeCode?  I would do : `when [mv_Loan_Ext1].[LoanPurposeTypeCode] between1 and 7 then ... `

Comment: not sure if in that mess of a string if this is the peice that goes together. IIf([mv_Loan_Ext1]![LoanPurposeTypeCode]+0 Between 1 And 7,"Other home",IIf([FANoteIsParticipationPurchased]=1

Comment: would this be correct?           when [mv_loan].[LoanPurposeTypeCode] between 1 and 7 then 'Other Income' else [FANoteIsParticipationPurchased] = 1

Comment: The next part (iif), can go in the else part or another when part, depending on parenthesis.  You have to analysis what current code actually do.

Comment: This is what i have so far.  Can you please give me your thoughts.  I am picking apart that string.  I still have more of it i am working on but just want to make sure i am in the correct direction and not running into a rabbit hole.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Select             
case when [mv_loan].[LoanPurposeTypeCode] in ('008', '080') then 'QRLF-' + case FAReceivePatronage when 0 then 'NPAT' else 'PAT' end             
          when [SecDistrictIndustryCode] = '999' then 'Non-QRLF'             
          when [PriDistrictIndustryCode] = '999' then 'RHL' end

Comment: when [mv_loan].[LoanPurposeTypeCode] between 1 and 7 then 'Other Income' else [FANoteIsParticipationPurchased] = 1            
            
Case when [mv_FANote].[BranchNbr] = '092' then '100% GP' else 'PP' end            
          when [PatronagePoolCode] = '14' then 'FCE'            
          when [YBSAgStart] <> 'No'  Or when Trim [AgGrow_NoOperator] = Null then 0            
          when Trim [AgGrow_NoOperator] = "" Or Trim [AgGrow_NoOperator] = 'No' then 0 else 1 end